# JQuery on Change event handler not working in CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to activate a function call and pass on a file selection event. The following non JQuery works fine:

```
class AddBTS
  constructor: () ->

    document.getElementById('upload_JSON').addEventListener('change', @select_json_changehandler, false)


  select_json_changehandler: (evt) =>
    console.log 'evt = ', evt
```

I've tried the following, it performs the function call but the evt is undefined:

```
class AddBTS
  constructor: () ->

    $('body').find('#upload_JSON').on 'change', => @select_json_changehandler()

  select_json_changehandler: (evt) =>
    console.log 'evt = ', evt
```

How can I correctly do the first code example using JQuery - any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: do you have another jQuery getting called in your code if is that so then it might be getting conflicted with this one

Comment: This is the only JQuery call here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you are wiring up a different event handler for the change event and having that event handler call select_json_changehandler. You need to have a parameterized function as your event handler that takes in the event as an argument and then passes that event to select_json_changehandler as an argument.

```
class AddBTS
    constructor: () ->
        $('body').find('#upload_JSON').on 'change', (evt) => @select_json_changehandler evt

    select_json_changehandler: (evt) =>
        console.log 'evt = ', evt
```

Comment: Why not just pass `@select_json_changehandler` rather than making a pointless anonymous function?

Comment: @Aaron Dufour  can you demonstrate what you mean in an answer?

Comment: @AaronDufour I was only going so far as to how to answer his question of why it wasn't working. If I was going for how I actually would have done this it would look much different.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you pass `@select_json_changehandler` as the callback.  But in the second example, you wrap it in an anonymous function (`=> @select_json_changehandler()`), which prevents arguments from being passed.  If you pass the same callback as in the first:

```
$('body').find('#upload_JSON').on 'change', @select_json_changehandler
```

it should work as expected.